# Typescript: Wrong expected type for HOC props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React I have a hook that looks roughly like this (I know this is not how HOCs are created, that's not the issue):

```js
function useHoc<P>(Component: FC<P>) {
    return function ComponentWithHoc(props: P) {
        return <div>
            <Component {...props} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

The usage of this hook looks like this:

```js
useHoc<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent)
```

When enabling Typescript's `strict-mode`, the usage of `Component` here as a child gets the following error:

```
Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P'.
  Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

My questions are:

1. Why does TS expect the generic type P to extend `IntrinsicAttributes`?
2. How do I make `Component` (which could be any component) accept `P` as its props?

Searching online I saw multiple suggestions but none helped alleviate the issue.

Adding The following **does not** solve the issue:

```js
<Component {...(props as P} />
```

Adding the following **does** solve **this** issue:

```js
useHoc<P extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>
```

But, it breaks all **existing** usages (as none of the prop types like `MyComponentProps` fit the constraint of `extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes`).

I tried replacing `FC` with `ComponentType`, and also replacing the generic `P` for props, with `C` for component and using `ComponentProps<C>` instead of `P`, but both resulted in the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your HOC function, create a function that takes `P & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` as props argument:

```
function useHoc2<P>(Component: FC<P>) {
    return function ComponentWithHoc(props: P & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes) {
        return <div>
            <Component {...props} /> // Okay
        </div>
    }
}
```

Note that by default, `JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` only contains optional props ([namely `key?`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6ca99826a8a8b6f6b9b89644602ae96d0ce024e9/types/react/index.d.ts#L130-L132)), so it should not break any of your legacy code:

```
function HelloComponent(props: { hello: string }) {
    return <div />
}

const Hello2 = useHoc2(HelloComponent)

function Main() {
    return <Hello2 hello="world" /> // Okay
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQFDPkCuAdhsBJ3OwDOSABIQ0AHgAKAPgAUhapE5JOMAFwFC0mQEpczOEbgMY7KPw7cYvfovB9VMAOrAYACzFo5YKmEGaUvo4hsZhpub8EgAmwABuMqFhyXAS9spOuAB0Ob4Q-mQA9DJwhYVwAKJQVFCaACoAnmBIcADkUq1wwIJwnBDwKIKCwADmnCgARgA2LTAQcDBNLa0AkmpQwJzDaACCMDAbE+wwSIKtWXIATADMl5e6SckShbEJjyTMH2xcPHwCwl5LjoFEpHGpNEQdMFHhELBQfjY-ukwS43J5xD4-AE4FI4AAyOAAKQAygANLJrA6bbZ7KlHE6CaEpIywqKvRLMp7IlRqbK5LFFEplOAAeQA1igGo8ws92e9PqwrL9+CIkFMphBuU5MflsXh3GqNZpBFTOCNSEzjKzUq9Sokvmg+Ca4Kr1RBLnAALz-UTiS5yV0arVqB7fay2OAAWRQmzklpZSDMcIkgfdcANbs9tAA7tAptFaHbSuVxZLPkA)

Comment: This is a solution to my problem, but in my specific case I then get the error `'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to ...`. By applying `as P & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` I managed to suppress the error but I wonder why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve] I might be able to further look into it, otherwise it is impossible to tell without further details on your specific case.

Comment: BTW it might be worthy of a new question instead.